# Code for checking write-permissions for directories in Win2K/XP

Tags: c++, windows, security, permissions, atl

Greetings!

I am trying to check directory write-permissions from within a Windows MFC/ATL program using C++. My first guess is to use the C-standard _access function, e.g.:

```
if (_access("C:\mydir", 2) == -1)
   // Directory is not writable.
```

But apparently on Windows 2000 and XP, _access can't determine directory permissions. (i.e. the Security tab in the Properties dialog when you right-click on a directory in Explorer) So, is there an elegant way to determine a directory's write-permissions in Windows 2000/XP using any of the Windows C++ libraries? If so, how?

Thanks

Evan

Comment: _access is not part of standard C (hence the leading underscore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call CreateFile with GENERIC_WRITE access to check this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx

It's not a C++ library but it still counts as elegant because it directly does what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Use sec api.
You can ask on Adv. Win32 api newsgroup :
news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
where it has often been discussed (C/C++ code)

Answer (score 1):

There are many [Windows security functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375742(VS.85).aspx), although I wouldn't call their usage particularly elegant. I would recommend GetNamedSecurityInfo as a general solution, but the CreateFile solution has a certain simplicity and directness which I can also appreciate. :)